# Why are mailboxes unsecure?

Tags: vulnerability, physical

Why can anyone go up to a mailbox and just take the mail out of it? Some mailboxes, like at townhouses and apartments, have locks, but the mailboxes at single family homes that I have seen do not. Isn’t the information unsecure? Why hasn't this changed?

Comment: I think you answered your own question?

Comment: To the people voting to close as off topic: Isn't physical security part of the site scope?

Comment: @Anders yes, physical security of information can be on topic. This question is .... not. "Is an unsecured container of information unsecure?"

Comment: @schroeder thank you for the comment. I modified the post to ask why mailboxes are unsecure instead of asking whether mailboxes are secure.

Comment: Put a lock on the mailbox. I'm still not sure where you are going with all this.  Who is supposed to "change" this? People went for decades (centuries) without locks on their house doors, either.

Comment: Because convenience is always more important than security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not secure. Anyone can just walk up the the mailbox and steal your mail. Depending on where you live, this could be very helpful for stealing your identity. And if nothing else, it is great for anyone who wants to spy on you.

So why do mailboxes look like this? Because it's practical. No need for you to fiddle with a key when you're in your dressing gown getting your mail in the morning. You could argue that the risk outweight the benefit, and I might even agree, but the point is that it's a trade off.